# Parse multiple hostnames from string

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I am trying to parse multiple hostnames from a string using a Regex in C#.

Example string: `abc.google.com another example here abc.microsoft.com and another example abc.bbc.co.uk`

The code I have been trying is below:

```
string input = "abc.google.com another example here abc.microsoft.com and another example abc.bbc.co.uk";
string FQDN_Pat = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])(\.([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))*$";

Regex r = new Regex(FQDN_Pat);
Match m = r.Match(input);         
while (m.Success)
{
    txtBoxOut.Text += "Match: " + m.Value + " ";
    m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

The code works if the string fits the pattern exactly e.g. `abc.google.com`.

How can I change the Regex to match the patterns that fit within the example string e.g. so the output would be:

Match: abc.google.com 
   Match: abc.microsoft.com 
   Match: abc.bbc.co.uk

Apologies in advance if this is something very simple as my knowledge of regular expressions is not great! :) Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Updating the Regex to the following (removing the `^` and `$`):

```
string FQDN_Pat = @"([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)(\.([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA‌​-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))";
```

Results in the following output:

Match 1: abc.g 
   Match 2: oogle.c 
   Match 3: abc.m 
   Match 4: icrosoft.c 
   Match 5: abc.b 
   Match 6: bc.c 
   Match 7: o.u

Comment: first - remove `^` from the beginning and `$` from the end - they mean that matching should start at the first char and finish at last char which requires string exactly matching

Comment: FYI: You can shorten `([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])` to `([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)`

Comment: FQDN's end in a dot (`.`). None of them are FQDN because they don't end in a dot. I corrected the title and problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the regexp is quite complicated I tried to simplify it a bit. So what I've done was to

1. Remove `^` and `$` to make the regexp match anywhere
2. Simplify characters that you match to , so instead of `([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])` i'm using `([a-zA-Z0-9])+` which means look for any alphanumeric sequence with length higher than one (the `+` sign means that you match to a char that appears once or more). Let's call it `X`. If the rules for names in FQDN are more complex please modify this value
3. Expression for finding FQDN is `X(\.X)+`. This can be viewed as sequence of chars followed by **one or more** sequences, all are separated  by dots (`.`). 
   Substitiuting `X` you have full expression given as

   ```
   string FQDN_Pat = @"([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.([a-zA-Z0-9])+)+";
   ```

which actually matches to your example but I suggest you read C# regexp manuals for further references in case there are some tricks in domain names

Answer (score 1):

You get this behavior because you are only matching the string that contain nothing else but your pattern. You are using `^` (start of the string) and `$` (end of the string). If you want to match your pattern anywhere in the input string remove those characters from the pattern.